# Is the set $V$ = { $([t], [g], [t], [j]): t,g,j∈$Z$,[2t+j] = [0]$} a subspace of vector space $(\mathbb Z_3)^4$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, modular-arithmetic

Is the set $V$ = { $([t], [g], [t], [j]): t,g,j∈Z,[2t+j] = [0]$}  a subspace of vector space $(\mathbb Z_3)^4$?

I am inclined to think that it is a subspace. However, I cannot find any basis for the subspace, which makes me doubt my suggestion that it is a subspace (as every subspace must have a basis).

Is (1,0,1,1),(0,1,0,0) the basis if the subspace? It seems that the vectors are not linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

*Note:*  All variables are taken as elements of $\Bbb{Z}_3$, so the equivalence class brackets are suppressed for readability.  Since $\Bbb{Z}_3$ is a *field*, the usual tools of linear algebra apply.

It might be clearer to initially give all the coordinates separate variable names, then impose relations:
$$
V = \bigl\{ (t, g, u, j) \bigm| u - t = 2t + j = 0 \bigr\},
$$
which you can write as a $2 \times 4$ matrix over $\Bbb{Z}_3$.  (There's one column for each generator and one row for each relation.)
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$

In other words, $V$ is the **kernel** or **nullspace** of the linear transformation represented by the matrix $A$.  This subspace has dimension $4-2=2$ with basis
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \;
\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
\right\}.
$$

Comment: I also though of this basis. However, it seems that it does not fall under the definition as the basis is not linearly independent ( I can find $c_1, c_2$ $∈ F$ such that $c_1$ is not 0 or $c_2$ is not 0)

Comment: Have another look at the definition of *linearly independent.*  The **only** linear combination of those two vectors that yields the zero vector is the trivial combination (both coefficients are zero).

Comment: If I take $c_1 = 3$ and $c_2 = 6$, then I get (3,6,3,3) = (0,0,0,0). As $Z_3$ = { [0], [1], [2] }, then [3] is [0] and [6] is [0].

Comment: Remember that $6=3=0$ in $\Bbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: But if it is some random field $F$? As it seems that 6 = 3 = 0 if $c1,c2∈Z_3$.

Comment: The *definitions* and *techniques* described work over **any** field.  The particular basis (even the number of vectors in it) might depend on the field that all of this takes place in.